# Why can't GitHub Action find command of library that I just installed?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to set up a GitHub Action for license checking, and I want to use this tool (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/licensed-ci).

I simply want to run, and scan for any obvious licensing errors. They also have a setup-tool that I decide on trying to use (https://github.com/jonabc/setup-licensed). Here, there is this example of usage:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@master
- uses: jonabc/setup-licensed@v1
  with:
    version: '2.x' # required: must satisfy semver.validRange
    install-dir: /path/to/install/at # optional: defaults to /usr/local/bin
    github_token: # optional: allows users to make authenticated requests to GitHub's APIs
- run: npm install # install dependencies in local environment
- run: licensed list
```

I try to implement this, but have no GitHub token, and don't know what the installation path is for, so I leave those two out in my version.

My workflow looks like this:

name: "Update and check dependency data"

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  licensed:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - uses: jonabc/setup-licensed@v1
        with:
         version: 2.x
      - run: licensed list
```

This fails on "run licensed list" with this:

```
`find_config': Licensed configuration not found in /home/runner/work/malware/malware (Licensed::Configuration::LoadError)
```

I have no idea what this error means, should I somehow add a config file somewhere?

Here are the files located in the repository root directory:

```
-go.mod
-go.sum
-LICENSE
-README.md
-sss.md
```

Comment: Could you describe which files are located at your repository root directory?

Comment: added in a edit

Comment: I couldn't make it work as well here. Even adding `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: true` (as its an old action that still use `add-path`for the `install-dir` which is not possible to use anymore) to inform the github root directory to install the licensed command: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/2344539080?check_suite_focus=true (my workflow: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester.yml)

Comment: It looks like it is looking for a configuration file: https://github.com/github/licensed#configuration